# Remove item from QListView\QListWidget by string name

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

In PyQt4, How do I delete an item from the `QListView\QListWidget` by a name string?

```
def deleteItem(itemName):
    item = dialog.listWidget.indexFromItem(itemName)
    dialog.listWidget.takeItem(item)
```

This is what I've got so far, and obviously feeding string to `indexFromItem` is not working...

Comment: so is `inventoryList` a `listWidget` as well?

Comment: Sorry, I was replacing my own variables with generic ones and forgot to replace those. Fixed question post.

Answer (score 3):

First, look for the item in `listWidget` using `findItems`:

`items_list = dialog.listWidget.findItems(itemName,Qt.MatchExactly)`

This will return a list of matched `QListWidgetItem` with `itemName` (which should be a list of one item if there is only one item with `itemName`)

Second, call `dialog.listWidget.row()` to find row number of your found item(s).

Finally, detele that/those item(s) using `dialog.listWidget.takeItem()`

So at the end you function would look like this:

```
def deleteItem(itemName):
     items_list = dialog.listWidget.findItems(itemName,QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
     for item in items_list:
         r = dialog.listWidget.row(item)
         dialog.listWidget.takeItem(r)
```

Again, you have to make sure there are no items with same names otherwise they would be deleted all together.

Comment: items_list = listWidget.findItems(itemName,QtCore.MatchExactly)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MatchExactly'

There is this error, I used QtCore since it seems like MatchExactlyt is in the QtCore class, and I did not find Qt module... or did I import something wrong?

Comment: Oh, there it is, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly. Seems to be working! Thanks

Comment: @Nix...Yes..it depends on how you imported PyQt module...I've updated my answer...